# Access RDS, based on Specific Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, rds

1. I want to use RDS in specific aws region, with specific IAM user.

I used this: but its not working for me .....can some one help me in above

---

```
    {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1479355543600",
      "Action": "rds:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "rds:Vpc": "1"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

```
    {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt145591112222",
      "Action": "rds:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:rds:ap-southeast-1:ACC_ID:db:*"

    }
  ]
}
```

---

Getting an Error :

```
User: arn:aws:iam::123123123:user/rdstest is not authorized to perform: rds:DescribeDBInstances (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 32e9f1dd-1231-1231-a701-77103c93efc4)
```

Comment: In what region you have created RDS?

Comment: What call are you issuing, that generates that error? Are you specifying a `db-instance-id`?